# Has Intel Iris Pro Graphics 580 really only 128 MB of memory? How can I force it to use my normal memory too?

Tags: graphics-card, intel-graphics

It's embedded in Intel NUC Skull Canyon, a mini PC that's marketed as a gaming device (see its [product page](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/change-the-game-with-nuc.html)). I think that there must be a way to dedicate some of my DDR4 memory to the graphics chip. I tried to play GTA IV, but it's fixed to lowest settings because of not enough memory...

Or is Intel lying?

Comment: Your GPU does not meet the minimum specifications for GTA IV

Comment: The graphics driver already uses regular RAM as necessary. There should be no need to change any reservations or whatever.

Comment: Yes, but GTA IV says that there is only 128 MB of graphics memory available! @DanielB

Comment: Of course. Because regular RAM is much slower, it isn’t taken into consideration when querying the amount of graphics RAM. You’re lucky GTA IV is running at all, it’s a rather greedy game.

Comment: [here](https://gameplay.intel.com/GamesSettings/7347/93340/Intel%c2%ae%20Core%e2%84%a2%20i7-6870HQ%20Processor%20(8M%20Cache,%20up%20to%203.60%20GHz) , Intel gives the customers recommended settings for GTA V, and it detects 8 GB of memory here. Does it include the regular RAM automatically?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Intel Ark page](http://ark.intel.com/products/93341/Intel-Core-i7-6770HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz?q=i7-6770HQ) for the processor that comes with that computer. It does, indeed, only come with 128MB of eDRAM. Increasing the amount of RAM that an integrated graphics card can access is usually found in the BIOS. Look for a setting such as "Memory Sharing" or "Graphics Settings".

But, to be honest, you're probably never going to get the performance you're looking for out of an integrated GPU. You'd be much better off getting a computer with a discrete GPU or taking advantage of the Thunderbolt 3 port on that computer to install an [external GPU dock](http://www.razerzone.com/store/razer-core) and then put a discrete GPU in that.